# Estpost returns error for factor variables

Tags: stata

I am trying to output the `mean` and `sd` for continuous and factor variables with 
the *community-contributed* family of commands `estout` (`ssc install estout`).

The code that I used is the following:

```
sysuse auto,clear
estpost sum price length foreign bn.rep78, listwise 
esttab, cells("mean sd min max") nomtitle nonumber
```

However, I get the error:

> factor variables and time-series operators not allowed
>   r(101);

I was wondering whether it is possible to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

The following syntax is legal:

```
regress mpg bn.rep78
```

For `estpost` to work, you need to remove the `bn.` prefix from `rep78`:

```
estpost sum price length foreign rep78, listwise
```

However, if you want to summarize the `0/1` indicator variables for the categories of `rep78` (whose means are the category proportions), you will need to create them manually:

```
tab rep78, gen(rep78x)
estpost sum price length foreign rep78x* , listwise
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to generate dummies on the fly:

```
sysuse auto,clear

xi: estpost sum price length foreign i.rep78, listwise 
esttab ., cells("mean sd min max") nomtitle nonumber

----------------------------------------------------------------
                     mean           sd          min          max
----------------------------------------------------------------
price            6146.043      2912.44         3291        15906
length           188.2899      22.7474          142          233
foreign          .3043478     .4635016            0            1
_Irep78_2         .115942     .3225009            0            1
_Irep78_3        .4347826     .4993602            0            1
_Irep78_4        .2608696     .4423259            0            1
_Irep78_5        .1594203     .3687494            0            1
----------------------------------------------------------------
N                      69                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `xi` prefix will expand any factor notation and can be used with commands that do not support factor notation.